# Необходимо убрать горизонтальный скролл

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, прокрутка

Делаю учебный макет сайта.

Никаким образом не получается убрать горизонтальный скролл на [сайте](https://bulgakovd97.github.io/russian-travel/index.html)

Понимаю, что вылезают блоки за границы контейнера, но не получается задать им правильный размер.

Нужно без использования overflow: hidden.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

Почему без `overflow: hidden`? Его можно добавить для мобильной версии, там он подойдет как раз т.к. после перезагрузки страницы все становится норм и горизонтальны скролл пропадает, а для планшетов у тебя фотки большие, они вылазят за рамки экрана.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще-то лучше использовать классическое:

```
img{
  max-width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
```